# Displaying numbers on horizontal bar chart

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to display numbers on my stacked horizontal bar chart, and I have figured out how to make the numbers show. However, because I have some single and double digit numbers, the orientation of the numbers are a bit weird. Single digits show up differently than double digits. Does anyone have a recommendation on how I can change the orientation so that the horizontal stacked bars show horizontally oriented numbers?

I have tried doing textposition = "auto" on plotly.

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = publicstperc, 
                     y = publicstate_df.index,
                    orientation = "h", name = "Public",
                    marker_color = "rgb(41,84,140)",
                    text = publicstate_df["Number of Public Schools"],
                    textposition = "auto"))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = privatenpperc,
                     y = privatenpstate_df.index,
                     orientation = "h", name = "Private-Nonprofit",
                    marker_color = "rgb(86,149,232)",
                    text = privatenpstate_df["Number of Private-Nonprofit Schools"],
                    textposition = "auto"))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = proprietaryperc,
                     y = proprietarystate_df.index,
                    orientation = "h", name = "Proprietary",
                    marker_color = "rgb(179,232,255)",
                    text = proprietarystate_df["Number of Proprietary Schools"],
                    textposition = "auto"))
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0,100])
fig.update_layout(title_text = "School Types Participation by State",
                  barmode='stack',
                 height = 1250,
                 width = 1000)
fig.show()
```

I expected for the numbers to show vertically because it is a horizontal stacked chart, but I found that single digit numbers show horizontally.[This is what my plot looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DX53.png):

[image]

Comment: Please include data sample and all `import` lines for reproducibility. Be sure posted data and runnable code can generate your undesired plot from an empty Python environment.

Comment: @Ellaine Taz Ying Ho, Following the advice from Parfait will hugely increase your chances of a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `textangle=0` inside your `go.Bar(...)` calls to force the text to be horizontal in all cases.